# "Vários", "variado", "variam", quando o uso pode conter duas possibilidades?

Tags: gramática

Sempre noto o uso da palavra, é variado para se referir a algo que oscila entre dois ou mais valores, claro que também posso entender que até os valores seriam ajustados, mas algo como:

> Semáforos de duas cores variam entre vermelho e verde apenas

No entanto desde sempre (até aonde me lembro) ouvia pessoas corrigindo outras por comparações que pareciam exageradas, certa vez ouvi uma pessoa dizer algo como:

> Tenho várias canetas

Como a pessoa só tinha 4 camisetas a outra pessoa lhe corrigiu dizendo:

> Não é várias, isso são apenas "algumas"

Logo "aprendi" que *"várias"* era um numero considerável, que nunca encontrei o certo/aproximado e que *"algumas"* seriam um numero pequeno, mas com certeza qualquer quantidade acima de "um item", então a pergunta que tenho sobre isto é:

- "várias" se difere no uso de "variado" e "variam"?
- "várias" tem "quantidade" aproximada para o seu uso em uma frase?
- O "variado" (singular) seria diferente em quantidade de "variados" (plural)?

Comment: Responde-lhes com: «Desculpa, mas isso não são "algumas" camisetas, são apenas duas...» :)

Comment: No Priberam "várias" [é definido](https://dicionario.priberam.org/v%C3%A1rias) tanto como sinónimo de "8. diversos, muitos" como sinónimo de "9. diversos, alguns"!? A língua portuguesa é muito matreira...

Comment: Tenho várias camisetas. Os desenho nelas não variam. São todas iguais. Nem as cores são variadas. Todas são bem brancas com bolinhas vermelhas.

Comment: Acredito que a seguinte escala esteja correta: poucas - algumas - várias - muitas - imensas. Quanto a qual é mais correta em que contexto, bem, trata-se de relativização (ter 4 sapatos apenas parece pouco apenas a quem é privilegiado o suficiente para ter mais).